# categories inside the Edit Entry publish tab?

Tags: categories, entry, publish-layout

It is possible to display categories inside the Edit Entry publish tab with EE3, to facilitate the use of publishing ?

Does an add-on exist to display the categories on this first tab ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes of course it is possible. For that you just have to go into `layouts` of respected Channel. And then drag and drop the categories under Publish tab.[image: Screenshot of edit entry]

[image: Screenshot of layouts in Respected Channel]

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but it's not working for me. Using Version Chrome 63.0.3239.84 (64-bit), and EE 3.5.12. I can drag the Categories tab on the Edit form Layout page under the Publish tab, but once dragged, nothing happens. Unfortunately the Categories not appears inside the Publish tab.

Comment: Ohh dear EE 3.5.12 is the buggy version. You should use EE 3.5.11.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I will try to update to EE 3.5.13, and soon EE4........... come back to 3.5.12 could give me some headaches........ Thanks again for your tips, it's a nice solution. It is documented in the EE 3 documentation? Happy Xmas !!!! I'm jealous it works for you and not for me ;)

Comment: Yes, but little bit. https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/cp/channel/layouts/form.html and yaa VERY VERY HAPPY XMAS.... Don't worry it will be fine, and will also work for you :) Till then Enjoy XMAS time.